# Converting a 3 column text file to csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text, type-conversion

I have a text file in in .txt format and I need it in .CSV format. It has 3 columns: timestamp, weight, voltage.

Does anyone know a way to convert a .txt to .csv?

The data I have is in this format:

```
time_stamp      value     voltage 
1606148833000 1669.00    0.146
1606148641970 7256.000   0.907     
1606148642212 7090.000   0.886     
1606148642461 6880.000   0.860     
1606148642713 6727.000   0.841     
1606148642963 6646.000   0.831
```

I can't seem to format the above, there are 3 spaces (or a single tab) in-between values.

I've tried pandas, the built-in CSV module, bash shell, and none are working for me.

Comment: I know this may have been answered before but I didn't understand the answers, I'm new to data analysis out of the classroom. So please go easy on me.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: Those titles are not included in the actual txt file. I added them here for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',delim_whitespace = True)
df.to_csv('file.csv',index=None)
```

the key argument being `delim_whitespace = True`, judging by the sample data you posted

If this does not work please paste the error you get and all, or a bigger chunk, of your file

here replace 'file.txt' with the path to your txt file and 'file.csv' the name of the file you want this saved in

Comment: I'll do it right now, thank you for being so helpful :). ** I'll also add more of my dataset. I've moved to my desktop PC now. This is a tight deadline hence the haste.

Comment: Oh wow, it worked. Thank you so much. I owe you big time. Thank you for being kind and understanding.

Comment: Glad it worked, good luck with the rest of it